# Pandas Series: maximum recursion error when replacing empty lists

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas `Series` containing lists. I wanted to replace empty lists with `NaN`.
My first approach was using `.replace`, but that unexpectedly gave me a maximum recursion error:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as 
ts = pd.Series([[1], [2, 3], [], [4]])
ts.replace([], np.nan)

RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

I achieved my result using

```
ts[ts.apply(len) == 0] = np.nan
```

but can anyone help me understand why the `.replace` approach fails?

Comment: in `0.23.1` I get `Kernel died, restarting` in anaconda, so it seems bug.

Comment: Since you can pass a list as to_replace parameter in pandas replace function it assumes you are passing in a list of values you want to replace. It then probably fails when this list is empty.

Comment: I think there is main general problem - poor./ buggy working pandas functions with non scalar values in Series :(

Comment: I suggest submitting this issue here: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the pandas documentation:

```
Series.replace(to_replace=None, value=None,...)

to_replace : str, regex, list, dict, Series, int, float, or None

list of str, regex, or numeric:    
- First, if to_replace and value are both lists, they must be the same length.
- Second, if regex=True then all of the strings in both lists will be interpreted as regexs otherwise they will match directly. This doesn’t matter much for value since there are only a few possible substitution regexes you can use.
- str, regex and numeric rules apply as above.
```

Pandas will mistake the to_replace value of [] for a list of strings to match, where it tries to replace its contents rather than the empty list itself. This causes the error. (So whatever the replace function does in this case, it will not work for empty lists - the OP's code snippet does not work in my environment, but I get a different error message.)

Comment: Thanks, the explanation makes sense. I have also submitted a bug report to pandas, I will wait for them to confirm

Answer (score 2):

This is more efficient and works correctly:

```
ts[ts.str.len() == 0] = np.nan
```

While you might think `ts.str` gives you strings, that is not all it can do!  When a Series contains lists, the `.str` accessor still supports slicing, `len()`, and more--they just mean slightly different to when the Series contains strings.  So `.str` is very useful for operating on Series of lists.